# Summing a (partial) harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis

Given that a is a real number greater than 1, what is the value of

$$S = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n$$ where $S_n = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{an-i}$, i.e.,
$$S_n = \frac{1}{an - 1} + \frac{1}{an - 2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{an - n}$$

I have chosen that if $a > 1$, S converges to a finite number, but I can't seem to arrive at an exact answer (which is what I need).

Thanks for any insights you can give.

Ron

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$S_n(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{an-i} = \dfrac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{a-\dfrac{i}n} $$
Note that the above is nothing but a Riemann sum. Hence,
$$S(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{a-\dfrac{i}n} = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{dx}{a-x} = -\left. \log(\vert a-x \vert) \right \vert_{0}^1= \log(\vert a \vert) - \log(\vert a-1 \vert)$$
Hence, we have
$$S(a) = \log\left(\left \vert \dfrac{a}{a-1}\right \vert\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{an-i}
= \sum\limits_{i=an-n}^{an-1} \frac{1}{i}
= H_{an-1}-H_{an-n-2}
$
where
$H_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1{i}$.

We now use the result that
$H_n = \ln(n)+\gamma+O(1/n)$
where $\gamma\approx 0.577$ is Euler's constant.

$\begin{align}
H_{an-1}-H_{an-n-2}
&= \ln(an-1)-\ln(an-n-2)+O(1/n)\\
&= \ln\big(\frac{an-1}{an-n-2}\big)+O(1/n)\\
&= \ln\big(\frac{an(1-1/(an))}{n(a-1)-2}\big)+O(1/n)\\
&= \ln\big(\frac{an(1-1/(an))}{n(a-1)(1-2/(n(a-1)))}\big)+O(1/n)\\
&= \ln\big(\frac{an}{n(a-1)}\big)
+\ln\big(\frac{1-1/(an)}{1-2/(n(a-1))}\big)+O(1/n)\\
&= \ln\big(\frac{a}{a-1}\big)
+\ln\big(\frac{1-1/(an)}{1-2/(n(a-1))}\big)+O(1/n)\\
&= \ln\big(\frac{a}{a-1}\big)+O(1/n)\\
\end{align}
$

for
$n > \max(2/a, 4/(a-1))$,
since,
for $0 < z < 1/2$,
$0 < -\ln(1-z)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k}
< \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k
= \frac{z}{1-z}
< 2z
$.